# IOS 7.1 UITabBarItem titlePositionAdjustment and imageInsets

Tags: objective-c, uitabbaritem, ios7.1

For previous versions of iOS 7 when I needed to shift the position of the title and image (usually an icon) on a `UITabBarItem` two settings were required.

`myViewController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 15);`
`myViewController.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(-15, 0);`

This however introduced double the inset size for the image since the 7.1 update of iOS. Below is an answer based on my findings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line from above is no longer required as the line

`myViewController.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(-15, 0);`

now also moves the image appropriately.